# Finding if there's at least one attribute in common in a set

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a validation using an Oracle SQL query, and the idea is:

There are items, and to every item there could be more than one suppliers.

I have a set of items (in a shopping bag) and want to verify if there is at least one common supplier between them. That means that **all** the items in the bag share **at least one** supplier.

Simplifying, the tables are:

BAG table with bag_id and item columns.
SUPPLY table with item and supplier columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a list of suppliers that match more than one item, with the most common suppliers on top

```
SELECT SUPPLY.supplier, COUNT(SUPPLY.item) item_count
FROM BAG
JOIN SUPPLY
  ON BAG.item = SUPPLY.item
GROUP BY SUPPLY.supplier
HAVING COUNT(SUPPLY.item) > 1
WHERE BAG.bag_id = ? --substitute bag_id
ORDER BY COUNT(SUPPLY.item) DESC
```

If you need to find suppliers that match ALL items in the bag, then use this query:

```
SELECT SUPPLY.supplier
FROM BAG
JOIN (SELECT bag_id, COUNT(*) as item_count FROM BAG GROUP BY bag_id WHERE bag_id = ?) bag_count
  ON BAG.id = bag_count.bag_id
JOIN SUPPLY
  ON BAG.item = SUPPLY.item
GROUP BY SUPPLY.supplier
HAVING COUNT(SUPPLY.item) = bag_count.item_count
WHERE BAG.bag_id = ?
```

You can check if the list is empty to determine if no common suppliers exist by wrapping this with an `EXISTS` statement.

Comment: Actually the query returns how many items each supplier supplies, if they supply more than one item.  I guess I can compare the top result with how many items are on the list. Still, not exactly what I asked, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: By common supplier - did you mean common for any or common for all?

Comment: I mean common among all the items. As in, there's at least one supplier that supplies all the items.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when exists
                       (
                        select 1
                        from bag b
                             inner join item i on i.id = b.item_id
                             inner join supplier s on s.id = i.supplier_id
                                                   and s.is_main = 'Y'
                       )
             then 'Y'
             else 'N'   
       end contains_main_supplier                   
from dual
```

Comment: Can´t really tell, but isn't that query just returning the main suppliers of each item?

Comment: The query returns what you asked for i.e. it return does the bag contain at least one main product i.e. in your terms 'ant to verify if there is at least one common supplier between them'

Comment: Actually when I said a common supplier, I meant a supplier that is shared among all the items. A supplier that all items have in common. Sorry if I expressed it wrong..